# Operaciones con valores dentro de un array PHP

Tags: mysql, php7

Tengo que sacar el promedio de ventas de los últimos seis meses por referencia, teniendo en cuenta las siguientes anotaciones:

1. Si en un mes las ventas de la referencia fue de 0, no tener en cuenta para el promedio.
2. Debo calcular la diferencia en porcentaje entre meses: Si la diferencia supera el 20% también debo sacarlo del promedio.

Inicie por medio de un query para sacar las ventas. Luego los ingrese en un array de la siguiente manera:

```
// Se crea un array con los valores de las ventas
$ventas = array($seis_meses, $cinco_meses, $cuatro_meses, $tres_meses, $dos_meses, $pasado_mes);
```

Posteriormente, quito los meses que estén en 0; de la siguiente manera:

```
// Se filtran las ventas para eliminar los valores de cero
$ventas_filtradas = array_filter($ventas, function ($venta) {
    return $venta != 0;
});
```

Ahora bien, por medio de un for recorro el array para iniciar los cálculos

```
//Se recorren los valores del array filtrado para iniciar comparaciones y cálculos
for ($i=1; $i < count($ventas_filtradas) ; $i++) { 
    $dmes = (float)$ventas_filtradas[$i-1]-(float)$ventas_filtradas[$i];//Se resta número anterior menos el número nuevo
    $dmes = (float)$dmes/(float)$ventas_filtradas[$i-1];//El resultado de la resta anterior, se divide entre el número anterior
    $dmes = (float)$dmes*100;//El resultado de la división anterior, se multiplica x 100 para obtener el valor del porcentaje
    $dmes = abs((float)$dmes);//Se obtiene el valor absoluto de la operación anterior
    $dmes = number_format((float)$dmes, 2, '.', '');//Se formatea el número con dos decimales
}
```

Hasta acá voy bien, pero sinceramente no he podido encontrar la forma de comparar y/o calcular teniendo en cuenta el 2 punto (Si la diferencia supera el 20% también debo sacarlo del promedio) y a partir de eso calcular el promedio. Si alguien me puede echar una mano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya tienes la base para calcular el porcentaje, básicamente lo que te faltaría es, por ejemplo, ir agregando los valores a un nuevo arreglo en el que finalmente te bases para realizar el promedio.

Además, se puede simplificar, por ejemplo no hace falta el último paso para formatear el valor del porcentaje con una cantidad de decimales. Por otro lado, yo siempre trato de usar nombres de variables que sean significativos, pues eso hace más legible el código.

Yo haría algo como:

```php
$ventas_no0 = array_filter($ventas, function ($venta) {
    return $venta != 0;
});
if (count($ventas_no0) == 0) die ('no hay ventas');
$ventas_prom = array($ventas_no0[0]);
for ($i=1; $i < count($ventas_no0) ; $i++) { 
    $diferencia_mes = abs((float)$ventas_no0[$i-1]-(float)$ventas_no0[$i]);
    $porcentaje_dif = $diferencia_mes / (float)$ventas_no0[$i-1] * 100;
    if ($porcentaje_dif <= 20) {
         $ventas_prom[] = $ventas_no0[$i];
    }
}

print_r($ventas_prom)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @jachguate, se me olvidó comentar algo. Resulta que si entre los seis meses hay diferencias superior del 20%se debe tomar solamente el mes con mejor venta. Por ejemplo: Desde enero se registra las siguientes ventas de X referencias; En enero 100 unds, en febrero 250 unds, en marzo 400 unds, en abril 700 unds, en mayo 1000 unds y en junio 1500 unds... Si aplico la formula durante todos los meses hay una diferencia del 20%,. En ese caso se debe tomar el mes con mejor ventas... Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Creo que la descripción es clara. Si comprendes el código que publicaste más el de mi respuesta, esperaría que estés en capacidad de escribir el código para resolver esa otra parte.  Por simplicidad en el análisis, puedes hacerlo con un if y un nuevo ciclo sobre el arreglo de ventas. Ya con un mayor expertís, podrías ir llevando el valor máximo en este mismo ciclo y utilizarlo al final. Pero al inicio es mejor mantener los conceptos simples.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió muchísimo. Saludos